# Update many heroku Apps with one Rails Project

Tags: heroku-postgres, heroku-toolbelt

I'd like know if is possible to have a single Rails App, where i have many different clients using this same App, where every single client have your own PostGreSQL DB in Heroku, so we have the same project to be updated for all this clients when i do the pushs to Heroku.

Do you know if it's possible to be done?

And how to ignore the database.yml file in updates, because every single client has your own DB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can but you probably shouldn't!

You can attach any number of Heroku Postgres instances to a Heroku app. You'll see that each instance you create adds a connection string to the list of environment variables - listed under the App's settings tab.

You can map the key string to a customer - via some unique identifier. You would then need to have an interceptor to bind the connection to the relevant database - or chose the relevant connect from a pre-bound list - and add it into the request context for each request.

It's a messy approach and not recommended. What would be slightly less messy is if you created a separate schema per customer instead. This way you bind to a single database instance and retain your database.yml config. But, each customer has their own dedicated schema. However, these are more architectural concerns that Heroku capabilities. From a Heroku perspective, both multi-database and mutli-schema approach is possible.

It should be noted that neither approach would give you any more referential integrity at the application logic level than standard roles and permissions with adequate auth mechanisms... All schemas and/or databases will be visible to the same application regardless of its separation at the database level. So, really there's little tangible benefit to it.

Comment: thank you for the tips, travega! I'll check what will be better to do..